# How do you get SQL to recognize WHERE column = NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In microsoft SQL, I have the following statement (roughly):

```
UPDATE sometable 
   SET somecolumn = @somevalue 
 WHERE somecolumn = NULL;
```

`@somevalue` is set previously in the script.

This runs fine and SQL tells me zero rows are affected. There are five rows were somecolumn is NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To answer the question in the title literally you would use `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`. This option is (correctly) deprecated though and you should just use `IS NULL`

Answer (score 17):

You have to use IS NULL instead to test for a NULL value in the column.

```
 UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn = @somevalue WHERE somecolumn IS NULL;
```

Comment: A NULL value cannot be equal to any value even to another NULL.

Comment: @Peter: NULL isn't a value -- it's a placeholder for the *lack of any value*

Comment: IIRC null is defined as 'unknown'. The comparison of two unknowns is false.

Comment: @james: The comparison of two unknowns is unknown.

Answer (score 4):

Try *IS NULL*

```
UPDATE sometable 
   SET somecolumn = @somevalue 
 WHERE somecolumn IS NULL;
```

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/21/431329.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Joe is right. Nothing can equal null. It can only be null, so therefore,

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET mycolumn = @value 
WHERE anotherColumn IS NULL
```

Comment: Nothing can equal null when it comes to making mistakes with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

[ANSI SQL defines NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) as not equaling anything - even another instance of NULL. The canonical way around that is to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

There's also the MS SQL Server option `SET ANSI_NULLS`. Turning this option off has the effect of having `WHERE x = NULL` do exactly what you expect. It also, however, will include any `NULL` values in a query like `WHERE x <> 'abc'` - which may not be what you'd expect. This option is connection specific, so changing it for your connection will not affect others. You can also set a default setting at the database level. When creating a stored procedure, the option is captured at *creation* time - not runtime.

Another trick is to construct a query like `WHERE ISNULL(x, '') = ISNULL(@x, '')`. I don't think that's SARGable, so performance isn't nearly as good as `WHERE (x IS NULL AND @x IS NULL) OR (x = @x)`, but it's a lot nicer to write and dynamically build.

Oh - and, since we're talking ANSI SQL. The ANSI SQL version of `ISNULL` is `COALESCE`.